# forget scrolling history by not using window.scroll()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I can't place my window.scroll(0,0) anywhere, it break will my transition.  because the item and content is align side by side, when I scroll either one side, and i come back, the scroll history isn't the same anymore

```js
$(function(){
    $('.item').on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('slideLeftItem');
        $('.content').show(0,'', function(){
            $('#back').show();
        }).addClass('slideRightContent');
    });
    
    
    $('#back').on('click',function(){
        
        $('.item').show().removeClass('slideLeftItem');
        $(this).hide();
        $('.content').removeClass('slideRightContent').once('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', 
            function() {
                 $(this).hide();
            });
        });
});
```

```css
.content{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
right: -200px;
top: 0px;
background: blue;
transition: 0.4s;
}

.item{

transition: 0.4s;
}

.slideRightContent{
    right: 0px;
}


.slideLeftItem{
    left: -200px;
}

#back{
    display:none;
    height: 20px !Important;
    background: grey !Important;

}

.content, .item{
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}

.phone{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
  transition: 0.4s;
   width:200px;
    border: 10px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="back">< back</div>


<br>
<div class="phone">
    
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="content">My content</div>

            
    <div class="item">item 2</div>
<div class="content">My content 2</div>
    
            
    <div class="item">item 3</div>
<div class="content">My content 3 is long My content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is long My content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is long My content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is longMy content 3 is long</div>
    
</div>
```

As u can see in my above demo, when the content page is long and u scroll up (or use window.scroll(0,0)) to read, u clicked back, it doesn't stay at where the user previously at.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the desired behavior is? I'm having a hard time understanding the problem.

Comment: @MarcoDelValle because the item and content is align side by side, when I scroll either one side, and i come back, the scroll history isn't the same anymore..

Comment: @JohnSt By "scroll history" do you mean scroll position? Scrolling doesn't have a history.

Comment: @JohnSt By that's what I mean. I can do like, when people click on the item, get the scroll position, and when they come back from the content, scroll back to the position, but the transition (animation) break.

Comment: To clarify... Have you tried reading/setting `window.scrollTop` ? You can animate this property if required.

Comment: @Basic yes, it will flick

Comment: @Basic I try to mimic native app's animation, I wouldn't want to animate scroll to top..